# JPGraph: Forcing Y-Axis values to display whole numbers

Tags: graph

I have a bar graph that displays a maximum value of 4, an integer. But the Y-axis values displayed are from 0.0 to 4.0.

I want the y-axis to display integer values, not in decimal form.

Can I explicitly do this in the JPGraph library?

Thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the scale to integer, e.g. $graph->SetScale('textint')